# Using \not together with custom commands

Tags: math-mode, macros

I have a command, alias of a complex expression, which I'm using frequently, and I would like to negate it without introducing new alias.

Simple solution introduces the third argument with default value, but it's messy to write `\myCommand[\neq]{arg1}{arg2}`, something like `\not\myCommand{arg1}{arg2}` is way better.

Example:

```
\newcommand{\divides}[2]{\ensuremath{#1\mid #2}}
```

thanks for both answers, now I see where to dig in.

Comment: Why not define a new command `\myCommandNot{arg1}{arg2}` which is a negative version of your command?

Comment: @sigur well, I'd like to see a way to make it with default negation and keep one command, instead of 2.

Comment: @Sanya_rnd It can be done, altough it would be nice if you posted a minimal compilable example, so we don't have to fill the holes by ourselves.

Comment: @Manuel edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose a syntax with a *-variant rather than the `\not` prefix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newrelation}{mmo}{%
  % #1 is the command to define
  % #2 is the relation to be used
  % #3 (optional) is the alternative
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   {\NewDocumentCommand{#1}{smm}{%
     \IfBooleanTF{##1}{##2\not#2##3}{##2#2##3}%
    }%
   }
   {\NewDocumentCommand{#1}{smm}{%
     \IfBooleanTF{##1}{##2#3##3}{##2#2##3}%
    }%
   }%
 }

\newrelation{\EQ}{=}
\newrelation{\LESS}{<}
\newrelation{\divides}{\mid}[\nmid]

\begin{document}

$\EQ{a}{b}$ and $\EQ*{a}{b}$

$\LESS{a}{b}$ and $\LESS*{a}{b}$

$\divides{a}{b}$ and $\divides*{a}{b}$

\end{document}
```

Saying `\newrelation{\EQ}{=}` is equivalent to typing

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\EQ}{smm}{%
   \IfBooleanTF{#1}% true if * is present
    {#2\not=#3}%
    {#2=#3}%
}
```

while `\newrelation{\divides}{\mid}[\nmid]` is like typing

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\divides}{smm}{%
   \IfBooleanTF{#1}% true if * is present
    {#2\nmid#3}%
    {#2\mid#3}%
}
```

For example, since `\not\in` is wrong, you could do

```
\newrelation{\IN}{\in}[\notin]
```

and the results will be appropriately typeset. Similarly, `\not\mid` gives a bad result and `\nmid` should be preferred.

[image]

If you prefer using a prefix, here it is (same output):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newrelation}{mmo}{%
  % #1 is the command to define
  % #2 is the relation to be used
  % #3 (optional) is the alternative
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   {%
    \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{mm}{##1#2##2}%
    \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname negate\string#1\endcsname{mm}{##1\not#2##2}%
   }%
   {%
    \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{mm}{##1#2##2}%
    \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname negate\string#1\endcsname{mm}{##1#3##2}%
   }%
 }

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\negate}{m}{%
  \@ifundefined{negate\string#1}
    {\@latex@error{Undefined relation}{}#1}{\@nameuse{negate\string#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\newrelation{\EQ}{=}
\newrelation{\LESS}{<}
\newrelation{\divides}{\mid}[\nmid]

\begin{document}

$\EQ{a}{b}$ and $\negate\EQ{a}{b}$

$\LESS{a}{b}$ and $\negate\LESS{a}{b}$

$\divides{a}{b}$ and $\negate\divides{a}{b}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up work is required, but it can be done.  In essence, you have define various macros that perform the desired "A symbol B" for various symbols, and then you must define `\negate` to know how to negate each of these symbols, in turn.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor,mathtools}
\def\eqsym{=}
\def\gtsymbol{>}
\let\svmid\mid
\let\svgtsymbol\gtsymbol
\newcommand{\divides}[2]{\ensuremath{#1\mid #2}}
\newcommand{\equals}[2]{\ensuremath{#1\eqsym #2}}
\newcommand\greaterthan[2]{\ensuremath{#1\gtsymbol #2}}
\newcommand\negate[1]{%
  \ifx\divides#1\def\mid{\mathrlap{\,/}\svmid}\else%
  \ifx\equals#1\let\eqsym\neq\else%
  \ifx\greaterthan#1\def\gtsymbol{\mathrlap{\,\,/}\svgtsymbol}\else%
  \fi\fi\fi%
  #1%
}
\begin{document}

$\divides{1}{2} \quad \negate\divides{1}{2}$

$\equals{1}{2} \quad \negate\equals{1}{2}$

$\greaterthan{1}{2} \quad \negate\greaterthan{1}{2}$


$\divides{1}{2} \quad \equals{1}{2} \quad \greaterthan{1}{2}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

ADDENDUM:

One way to combine the possible ease of egreg's definitions with the syntax of my approach would be to use his MWE, with the additional definition:

```
\def\negate#1{#1*}
```

In that way,

```
$\EQ{a}{b}$ and $\negate\EQ{a}{b}$

$\LESS{a}{b}$ and $\negate\LESS{a}{b}$

$\divides{a}{b}$ and $\negate\divides{a}{b}$
```

would produce the same result as his MWE.